# Alert question status change inside code snippet

Tags: discussion, feature-request, stack-snippets

Every now and then, I've been frustrated when encountering a close questions after I finish writing a code snippet.

I've been coding inside a code snippet, trying to solve x problem. I finallly manage to solve it and I'm ready to post an awesome answer. I click `save and insert to post` just to encounter a yellow bar telling me the question was closed for y reason.

I think that yellow bar is a great idea, but it should alert users working on a code snippet.

Comment: Is it that the snippet editor is covering up the yellow bar? IIRC, the closure message shows up as soon as it happens, right?

Comment: Also, out of curiousity, is it that the questions turn out to be duplicates?

Comment: @BSMP, not really sure. But i think that could be the. My solution right now for this problem, is to duplicate my tab, work on a solution for the first. An check the status of answers, comments and question in an other.

Comment: @BSMP I have encounter with hold, duplicate, deletion and answered. Sometimes one jumps to a solution and doesn't check for duplicates.